# How to test components which render pieces of svg?

Tags: reactjs, svg, jestjs

I'm pretty new to react. I'm writing components which are going to be used within `<svg>` tag.

I would like to have tests for these components.
However, all my test are failing to recognize valid children of `<svg>` e.g. `<path>`, `<rect>` and `<circle>`, etc.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Layout } from './Layout';
import { LayoutAlignmentHorizontal, LayoutAlignmentVertical, LayoutFlow } from './Layout.enum';


it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const svg = document.createElement('svg');
  svg.setAttribute('xmlns','http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
    ReactDOM.render(<Layout flow={LayoutFlow.COLUMN}
                            horizontalAlignment={LayoutAlignmentHorizontal.LEFT}
                            verticalAlignment={LayoutAlignmentVertical.TOP}>
      <rect width={50} height={50} fill={'red'}/>
      <circle r={15} fill={'blue'} transform="translate(15 15)"/>
      <path transform="scale(.15)"
            d="M 10,30 A 20,20 0,0,1 50,30
               A 20,20 0,0,1 90,30
               Q 90,60 50,90
               Q 10,60 10,30 z"
            fill={'green'}/>
    </Layout>, svg);
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(svg);
});
```

Actual:

```
$ react-scripts test
 FAIL  src/containers/layout/Layout.test.tsx
  ● Console

    console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:506
      Warning: The tag <rect> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.
          in rect (at Layout.test.tsx:11)
          in g (at Layout.tsx:60)
          in g (at Layout.tsx:71)
          in Layout (at Layout.test.tsx:10)
    console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:506
      Warning: The tag <g> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.
          in g (at Layout.tsx:60)
          in g (at Layout.tsx:71)
          in Layout (at Layout.test.tsx:10)
    console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:506
      Warning: The tag <circle> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.
          in circle (at Layout.test.tsx:12)
          in g (at Layout.tsx:60)
          in g (at Layout.tsx:71)
          in Layout (at Layout.test.tsx:10)
    console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:506
      Warning: The tag <path> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.
          in path (at Layout.test.tsx:13)
          in g (at Layout.tsx:60)
          in g (at Layout.tsx:71)
          in Layout (at Layout.test.tsx:10)
```

Expected:
svg tags should be rendered

Comment: Have you tried rendering the `<svg>` tag in React so it knows the context of what it's trying to render?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this issue using a SVG component in my Jest test suite.

FWIW, you can just wrap the component with `<svg>` to make Jest tests pass:

```
test('something', () => {
  mount(<svg><MySVGComponent /></svg>)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [DoMiNeLa10](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6019272/dominela10)'s comment.

React should render the `<svg>` element, then it works :)

```
it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
    ReactDOM.render(<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <Layout flow={LayoutFlow.COLUMN}
                  horizontalAlignment={LayoutAlignmentHorizontal.LEFT}
                  verticalAlignment={LayoutAlignmentVertical.TOP}>
        <rect width={50} height={50} fill={'red'}/>
        <circle r={15} fill={'blue'} transform="translate(15 15)"/>
        <path transform="scale(.15)"
              d="M 10,30 A 20,20 0,0,1 50,30
                 A 20,20 0,0,1 90,30
                 Q 90,60 50,90
                 Q 10,60 10,30 z"
              fill={'green'}/>
      </Layout>
    </svg>, div);
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});
```